# Jquery $.ajax/$.post cannot find mvc controller method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-post

I have tried several different ways to try and call an MVC 4 controller method almost all of them have been 404s.

ive also looked at many different posts and websites trying to get it to work but i have had no success
my controller looks like this

```
public class AjaxController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult AjaxContactForm()
    {
        Data.DataUtilities.ForwardCustomerEmail();
        var pause = "";
        var result = "";
        return Json(result);
    }

}
```

the path of the controller is 
Portfolio(root)\Controllers\AjaxController.cs

almost every url that i have tried results in a 404

this is what i have currently

```
var params = {
             conName: contactName,
             conEmail: contactEmail,
             conMessage: contactMessage
             };
$.ajax({
    url: '<%:Url.Action("AjaxContactForm","AjaxController") %>',
    type: "post",
    success: function () {

    }
  });
```

ive tried

```
'<%:Url.Action("AjaxContactForm","Controller/AjaxController") %>'
'<%:Url.Action("AjaxContactForm","/Controller/AjaxController") %>'
'<%:Url.Action("AjaxContactForm","/Controllers/HomeController.cs") %>'
'/AjaxController/AjaxContactForm'
'Controller/AjaxController/AjaxContactForm'
'/Controller/AjaxController/AjaxContactForm'
```

ive done all these as well using a $.post but i can never hit the method.

what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
Url.Action("AjaxContactForm","Ajax")
```

`AjaxController` should be referenced as `"Ajax"`.

`HomeController` should be referenced as `"Home"`.

etc.

Comment: well that makes perfect sense and absolutely no sense at all, lol
thanks for your help